# How do you arrange a list in Python and then return it?

Tags: python

Hello I have the following python script, which obtains information from a list and concatena for a javascript that I import in a test application for my TCC.

```
import json

lista = [
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "aad_training",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa1.org",
            "TargetName": "empresa1"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "aad_account",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa1.org",
            "TargetName": "empresa1"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "AccountStructure",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa1.org",
            "TargetName": "empresa1"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "philippe",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa2.info",
            "TargetName": "empresa2"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "porto",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa2.info",
            "TargetName": "empresa2"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "obidos",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa3.net",
            "TargetName": "empresa3"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "coimbra",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa3.net",
            "TargetName": "empresa3"
        }
    }
]



    regexp = []
    target = []
    for chaves in lista:
        dicionario = chaves['ExceptionsAPI']
        target.append(dicionario['TargetName'])
        hostname = (dicionario['TargetHostname'])
        regexp.append(dicionario['ExceptionName'])



    regexp = str('|').join(regexp)
    print('\n Targets in the List'.join(target))

    print('\n We have the following exceptions for the company1:', regexp)

    print('\n We have the following domain:', hostname)
```

Output:

```
    empresa1
     Targets in Listaempresa2
     Targets in Listaempresa3
    ('\n We have the following exceptions for the company1', 'aad_training|aad_account|coimbra')
    ('\n  We have the following domain:', 'empresa3.net')
```

It's working, but I need help. I need you to go back to each 'TargetName' an organization like this below:

So, as you can verify, for each target name writes with print and returns me the correct organization of each 'ExecptionName' of each 'TargetName'

what I need and that for each target being 1 or 100 it returns to me this organization and assembleit automatically.

what I need and that the return is like this:

```
    The following targets are listed:

    Targets in the List: company1
    Targets in the List: company2
    Targets in the List: company3



    We have the following exceptions for the company1:
    your domain and: empresa1.org
    their targets are: aad_training;aad_account; AccountStructure, New

    We have the following exceptions for the company2:
    your domain and: empresa2.info
    its targets are: philippe;porto

    We have the following exceptions for the company3:
    your domain and: empresa3.net
    its targets are: obidos;coimbra
```

Comment: Please clean up the output to match the code you've posted. It is not clear what's your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below for automated listing of your requirements.

```
import re
lista = [
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "aad_training",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa1.org",
            "TargetName": "empresa1"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "aad_account",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa1.org",
            "TargetName": "empresa1"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "AccountStructure",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa1.org",
            "TargetName": "empresa1"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "philippe",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa2.info",
            "TargetName": "empresa2"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "porto",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa2.info",
            "TargetName": "empresa2"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "obidos",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa3.net",
            "TargetName": "empresa3"
        }
    },
    {
        "ExceptionsAPI": {
            "ExceptionName": "coimbra",
            "TargetHostname": "empresa3.net",
            "TargetName": "empresa3"
        }
    }
]


companies = set(filter(lambda y: re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$',y),map(lambda x: x['ExceptionsAPI']['TargetName'],lista)))

print(str('\n').join(set(map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1]}',zip(['Targets in the List:']*len(companies),companies)))))

for i in sorted(companies):
    print(f'We have the following exceptions for the {i}')
    clist = list(filter(lambda x:x['ExceptionsAPI']['TargetName'] == i,lista))
    hostname = set(map(lambda x:x['ExceptionsAPI']['TargetHostname'],clist))
    targets = set(map(lambda x:x['ExceptionsAPI']['ExceptionName'],clist))
    print(f'your domain and: {",".join(hostname)}')
    print(f'its targets are: {";".join(targets)}')
```

This will give you the expected output:

```
Targets in the List: empresa1
Targets in the List: empresa3
Targets in the List: empresa2
We have the following exceptions for the empresa1
your domain and: empresa1.org
its targets are: AccountStructure;aad_training;aad_account
We have the following exceptions for the empresa2
your domain and: empresa2.info
its targets are: philippe;porto
We have the following exceptions for the empresa3
your domain and: empresa3.net
its targets are: obidos;coimbra
```

Comment: perfect, it worked :)

Just one more doubt, imagine that I get a value in json in the TargetName and ExceptionName field with invalid characters such as (. Ç - _ ,) how not to run if I receive these values.

i want to allow a-z letters and numbers only.

Comment: You can use regex to check and skip [a-zA-Z0-9]+, anything that matches this would return true else false, skip the value for false.Also, please vote my answer. :)

Comment: can you help me in which part of the code I add regex?

i tried two places and it didn't work.